# Build Jar con Intellij **No hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en *.jar**

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

Estoy trabajando con intellij 2019.3 pero tengo problemas a la hora de ejecutar el .jar generado del proyecto.

Para generar el .jar File / Project Structure... /Poject Settings /Artifacts

[image: Create jar from modules]

Después de esto Build / Build artifact

A la hora de ejecutar por cmd java -jar **-jar el sistema me responde:

**No hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en **.jar**

Es extraño pues el archivo este generado y se indica la clase donde se encuentra el main.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.example.App
```

En el IDE el programa funciona sin problemas e indicándole la clase main mediante java -cp *.jar org.example.App también.

Comment: Revisando mi configuración el manifesto esta en `\src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` mientras que el tuyo esta en `\src\main\java\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`, prueba editar el tuyo porque yo siempre lo he visto en la raíz del jar

Comment: Correcto! muchas gracias.